# SWIG: How to pass a vector of complex numbers from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, swig, swig-template

%include <std_complex.i>

manager.i:21: Error: Unable to find 'std_complex.i'

Comment: You need to state a question and format the code.

Answer (score 1):

Swig documentation (*) says:

> some language modules support a subset of the above and some support
> additional STL classes. Please look for the library files in the
> appropriate language library directory.

therefore it appears that std_complex.i is not implemented for Java as the target language. The reason may be that Java does not have a data type for complex numbers.

In order to interface existing C++ code that uses complex numbers to Java with swig, you would have to write your own type maps or write wrapper functions in C++ that accept and return separated real and imaginary parts.

(*): https://swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html, search for complex.i